# Is there any way in Godot 3.5.x to round corners of images?

Tags: godot, godot3

Is there a way to do an apply a rounded corner to arbitrary images in Godot? I know we can fake it by adding transparent images over the corners:

[image: Rounded Corner Example image]

I know that we can create a `panel` with a `style box flat`, and make the corners of the panel rounded. But clipping the content of the panel *doesn't* clip the corners of the image inside the panel.

UPDATE: I am aware of a [special shader script](https://godotshaders.com/shader/set-corner-radius-for-texture/) that curves the edges of square images. It only works for square images. I don't know enough about shaders to make it work for other image sizes. Here is what it looks like in practice on non square images.

[image: non rounded corner example]

Comment: I have heard a rumor Godot4 might support this. But we are not able to move to Godot4 at this point in time.

Comment: Why not just use shader for that? https://godotshaders.com/shader/set-corner-radius-for-texture/

Comment: @BogdanKuštan Most shader code out there for rounded corners doesn't round the corners evenly unless the shape your shading is square. There surely is a way to round corners without having to resort to custom shader code.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot get the `Control` size inside the of the shader, so even if you get the correct coordinates, you would only be able to remove one corner. You could workaround that with a script that gives the shader the correct coordinates and size. Sadly the situation isn't much better in Godot 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to change the expand and stretch modes of the `TextureRect`, you can replace it with `Panel` and use a shader to add a `Texture` on it.

For example, something like this:

```
shader_type canvas_item;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void fragment() {
    COLOR = texture(tex, UV);
}
```

Of course, set the texture in the shader parameters.

Then you can apply an `StyleBoxFlat` on the `Panel` for the rounded corners.

Comment: Wow, that's a creative solution. I'm going to experiment with this!